# Need to change connection in SQL Postdeploy

Tags: sql, dacpac

This is the situation: The Dacpac and ISpac files are deployed with a Powershell script.
The result of the dacpac goes to Server1, the ISpac to Server2.

In post-deploy of the dacpac an account and credentials are added on Server1 along with some other configurations.

When that is done, the connection should be changed to Server2 done by :connect Server2, for some additional setup .
When testing in SSMS SQLCMD mode this works fine, but VS complains with error 72006: Fatal scripting error: Command Connect is not supported.

So, can it be done? And if it can, how?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what I try to do is not possible, but there is a workaround.

1. Create a dummy database project with an essentially empty database. 
   You can either use a publish script to basically not create anything, or you 
   can drop the database afterwards in your Powershell script.
2. Put your code in Postdeploy of the dummy project.
3. Test and deploy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that VS have activated the sql cmd mode that is a button in the query toolbar

[image: VS sql toolbar]

Comment: It was and is checked, so that's not it.